# Why can't I pass in a uniqueidentifier/GUID to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have this SP

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_test]    Script Date: 06/12/2010 11:47:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]  
    @id uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN

    select * from TestTbl where ProductId= @id

END
```

I then went to the SP with ms sql 2005 and clicked execute. It comes up with a box where I entered in the GUID. I copied and pasted it straight from my test database.

I get this error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'cac671b'.

So why can't I sent in GUIDs? even ones that are copied right from the database and must be valid as they where allowed into the db.

Comment: 100% agree with @marc_s on prefixes.  Just don't.  There is absolutely no benefit to using sp_ or usp_ or whatever in front of ALL procs.  Just like there's no benefit to naming tabls 'tblMyTable' or whatever.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Two hints:

- first of all, do **not** call your stored procedures `sp_(something)` - Microsoft specifically [warns against that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669.aspx)

> We recommend that you do not create
>   any stored procedures using **sp_**  as a
>   prefix. **SQL Server uses the sp_ prefix
>   to designate system stored procedures.**
>   The name you choose may conflict with
>   some future system procedure.

- secondly: I have no trouble calling your stored proc like this:

  ```
  EXEC proc_test 'B551F2C8-8380-491B-A51F-436E51CDD08F'
  ```

How are *you* calling your stored proc?? Show us!

Answer (score 8):

The message

> Incorrect syntax near 'cac671b'.

Must mean that it is trying to parse the GUID itself. Try delimiting it in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're copying-and-pasting a string. Can you declare and use it like this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test] 
    @guidstr varchar(37)
AS

DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier 
SET @guid = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @guidstr)
...
```

Comment: It's not too bad of an idea.  It's along the lines of what I was considering before I started searching how I would handle guids and came across this post.  I reckon this solution would only move the OP's problem to the CONVERT function call.

Comment: it works to me,  this is the solution to my trouble